# Buffering data for media player hangs tests in PyQt5

Tags: qt, pyqt5, pytest, buffer, qmediaplayer

I need to play audio *from memory*. For demonstration purposes, I loaded my .mp3 from hard-drive into memory. The audio loads and plays correctly, **but not in testing mode**.  Here's my code:

```python
from PyQt5.QtCore import QBuffer, QIODevice, QByteArray
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent

with open(r"C:\test_audio.mp3", "rb") as f:
    q_byte_array = QByteArray(f.read())

player = QMediaPlayer()
buffer = QBuffer(player)
buffer.setData(q_byte_array)
buffer.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly)

player.setMedia(QMediaContent(), buffer)
player.play()
```

When I try to run a test for this part, it hangs infinitely. Here's a minimal example of a test function for it to get stuck.

```python
from PyQt5.QtCore import QBuffer, QIODevice
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent

def test_media_player():
    player = QMediaPlayer()
    buffer = QBuffer()
    buffer.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite)
    player.setMedia(QMediaContent(), buffer)
```

[image]

(it does that even if QBuffer is filled with audio data)
There was a suggestion that it maybe needs the app event loop, is there any example how to implement that for testing? Or some other solution?

Comment: Please don't delete [a question marked as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73218309/2001654) just to create a new one that **is just the same**. Instead, if you don't agree with the reason of the closure, *edit* it and add comments explaining why you believe it is not a duplicate, so that it could be eventually be reopen.

Comment: My bad. After editing the post and reformulating the question it still hung there for an hour still closed. But yea, the suggested post had a different question, since my player works fine, it's just the testing that fails

Comment: Reopening is not immediate, it might take some time to the review, one hour is certainly *not* that much to wait. Also, as said, you should use comments to notify about changes or disagreement with closures, we cannot follow *all* posts. Be patient, this is not a help desk, things can take time, and in this period of the year there's also less people that can do something for that.

Comment: @Mirrah The `test_media_player` function doesn't actually test anything. All it does is create some temporary objects which are immediately garbage-collected. Please provide a proper [mre].

Comment: @ekhumoro the fragment of code doesn't test anything indeed because I demonstrated the minimal example of it enough to get stuck. After these lines of codes I intended to do the *actual* testing.
    assert player.mediaStatus()
    assert 1
or whatever. The result is still the same

Comment: @Mirrah The point is that your question does not give any relevant details at all about *how you are doing the actual testing*. You must provide a realistic example that can be used by others to reproduce the problem. Vague verbal descriptions are of little use.

Comment: @ekhumoro these 4 lines of code are enough to reproduce the problem of being on hold infinitely. What I write after them never gets executed anyway

Comment: @Mirrah No, it does not reproduce anything. After adding the line `test_media_player()` and running your so-called "minimal" example in a console, it will merely print a few Qt messages and exit normally. So the problem clearly lies elsewhere.

Comment: @ekhumoro your behaviour is different than my then. This is what I get [link](https://imgur.com/a/WrqnaTF)
No output, no tests passed, no tests failed

Comment: @Mirrah No, it's not really different. You aren't running the code in a **standard console / command-window**. You're running it in an IDE with some kind of testing utility and/or debugger, which you have not fully specified. Context is everything here, and you still haven't provided sufficient details. The example itself is not the source of the problem. The real problem is with exactly how you are running that example as a test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246999/discussion-between-mirrah-and-ekhumoro).